# VBA on click_ delete records of a table

Tags: vba, recordset

I am trying to delete the records of a table rather than deleting the records of a form. I have the following code, which does not work:

please can someone help.

```
Private Sub Cmd_X_Click()

Dim db As DAO.Database
Dim rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim rsCount As Integer

Dim BizNO As Field
Dim Bank_Role As Field

Dim i, j As Integer

Set db = CurrentDb()
Set rs_date = db.OpenRecordset("TRD_Pricing-In date_REAL")

Set PE_ID = rs_date.Fields("Pricing_Element_ID")
rs_date.MoveLast
rs_dateCount = rs_date.RecordCount

MsgBox (rs_dateCount)
MsgBox (Me.Pricing_Element_ID)
MsgBox (PE_ID.Value)

rs_date.MoveLast


For i = 1 To rs_dateCount

    If Me!Pricing_Element_ID = PE_ID Then
    rs_date.DELETE
    Else
    rs_date.MovePrevious
    End If

Next i


End Sub
```

Comment: "_Does not work_" is not a specific problem statement.

Answer (score 0):

In your for loop you are not comparing the right elements. When you do:

```
Set PE_ID = rs_date.Fields("Pricing_Element_ID")
```

you set PE_ID to the value of the Pricing_Element_ID of the first record. You intend to set a reference to it, and everytime the recordset advances to the next record, you want this reference to be updated. But that's not how it works. You have to get the field in the *current record* every time you advance the recordset. So you have to write:

```
If Me!Pricing_Element_ID = rs_date.Fields("Pricing_Element_ID") Then
```

Note: from experience I found the count of a recordset is not always accurate. So rather than a for loop, use a while loop:

```
While (Not EOF(rs_date))
    If Me!Pricing_Element_ID = rs_date.Fields("Pricing_Element_ID") Then
        rs_date.DELETE
    Else
        rs_date.MoveNext
    End If
Wend
```

Note also that there is no need to proces the recordset from last to first; just advance to next until EOF.